# Using MySQL to return row between to strings with date, but without year

Tags: mysql, string, date

I am currently working on a project in which I want to store commemorative days (like January 8th's World Leprosy Day) in a database. At this moment they're stored in a table which contains:

```
- an ID
- the date as varchar (stored European style, e.d. "8-01" for January 8th)
- length of the commemorative day (as some span multiple days)
- and the name
```

The reason I am storing the date as varchar is because the year is irrelevant, and I'm a bit reluctant to just store a year (e.g. 2013) in the database and truncate it.

But here's the problem: I can't seem to find a way to construct a query that will get the rows between dates. I think it's because the way the dates are stored in the database.

I already tried (given day = "8-01")
`SELECT * FROM comdays WHERE date(day) BETWEEN date("1-01") AND date("20-01")`

But to no avail.

Is there a way to get this thing going with strings? Or do I have to change the date column into a MySQL DATE format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you don't use standard datetime formats you make your life *a lot* more difficult. This is a *perfect* example of that.

Comment: @JohnConde true, but then again: using the normal structure required the use of a year (YYYYMMDD), and secondly: it's a bit less semantic for me, being a European. So that's why I (for now) chose to use a DDMM format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to keep non standard date field in MYSQL you will need to use the following format `0108`-> `mmdd` this format allows calculations.

It might also be worth reading the following answers to similar question [Save day and month in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043239/best-way-to-save-only-day-and-month-in-database)